# ¿Cómo crear un nuevo array usando FOREACH en C# para Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy realizando el siguiente ejercicio y no he podido dar con el método correcto para crear un nuevo array a partir de los resultados obtenidos en uno previo.
Los resultados obtenidos en studentGrades = new float [25]; (usé un Random.Range para obtener valores aleatorios) deben ubicarse en float[] passed; o float failed [];según sea el caso (>5 o <4.9).
¿Podrían colaborarme, por favor?

```
public float [] studentGrades = new float [25];
public float[] passed;
public float[] failed;
int studentCounterPassed;
int studentCounterFailed;

private void Start()
{
   
    for (int i = 0; i < studentGrades.Length; i++)
    {
        studentGrades[i] = Random.Range(1.0f, 10.0f);
    }

    foreach(float grades in studentGrades)
    {
        if (grades > 5)
        {
            studentCounterPassed++;
        }
        if (grades < 4.9f)
        {
            studentCounterFailed++;
        }
    }
    Debug.Log("Cantidad de estudiantes que perdieron: " + studentCounterPassed);
    Debug.Log("Cantidad de estudiantes que pasaron: " + studentCounterFailed);
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan. Por favor aclara tu pregunta, no es evidente lo que necesitas. Quieres construir un array y llenarlo dentro de un foreach? Cuál es la complicación?

Comment: Perdón. Quiero construir dos nuevos array. public float[] passed; y
public float[] failed; con base a los resultados obtenidos en public float [] studentGrades = new float [25];, utilizando foreach.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los arreglos son estructuras estáticas. Su tamaño no puede cambiar. Por ello, tienes 2 alternativas.

Usar arreglos del mismo tamaño:

```
int students = 25;
float[] studentGrades = new float[students];
float[] passed = new float[students];
float[] failed = new float[students];

foreach(float grade in studentGrades)
{
     if (grade > 5)
     {
          passed[studentCounterPassed++] = grade;
     }
     else
     {
          failed[studentCounterFailed++] = grade;
     }
}
```

O usar una estructura dinámica como `List`:

```
int students = 25;
float[] studentGrades = new float[students];
var passed = new List<float>();
var failed = new List<float>();

foreach(float grade in studentGrades)
{
     if (grade > 5)
     {
          passed.Add(grade);
     }
     else
     {
          failed.Add(grade);
     }
}
```

Nota que en este último caso puedes usar los contadores pero no es necesario. En su lugar, puedes usar la propiedad `Count` de las listas para saber cuántos elementos tienen.

Comment: ¡Wow! Me ha quedado claro, muchísimas gracias, Mateo.

Comment: @JuanRodriguez te deje varios enlaces en tu pregunta. Apredne a usar el sitio. La forma de decir gracias aqui, es votando y aceptando las respuestas que te sirvieron.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **Linq**, de esta forma ahorrarás mucho código:

```
var passed = (from s in studentGrades
              where s > 5
              select s).ToList();

var failed = (from s in studentGrades
              where s <= 5
              select s).ToList();
```

La primera consulta filtra los estudiantes aprobados obteniendo una lista de los mismos.

Por otra parte la segunda consulta obtiene una lista de los estudiantes que suspendieron.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```